# How to remove unwanted quotes using R?

Tags: r, string

I have been trying to manipulate this string to remove extra double quote at the start but have not been able to do it.

[image]

Comment: remove `^"(?=")` with nothing

Comment: Hi Shobhit. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a [curly quote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark). To remove it at the beginning of the string, use

```r
sub('^“', '', your_string)
```